# Mouse isn't recognized

Tags: usb, mouse

lsusb says:

```
chris@cnb:/var/log$ lsusb
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E620 USB Modem
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174f:1127 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Xorg.0.log:

```
(II) config/udev: Adding input device SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse (/dev/input/event9)
(**) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
(**) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: always reports core events
(**) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event9"
(II) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
(II) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
(II) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: Found relative axes
(II) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
(II) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: Configuring as mouse
(**) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
(**) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse" (type: MOUSE)
(II) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
(II) config/udev: removing device SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse
(II) SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse: Close
(II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Changing the USB-ports solved the problem. The modem has to be on the left port, the mouse on the right one. Don't ask why.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by the OP:

> Changing the USB-ports solved the problem. The modem has to be on the
>   left port, the mouse on the right one. Don't ask why

Answer (score 0):

Changing the USB port from 3.0 to 2.0 in my Toshiba Satellite L745 solved this problem. I am using Genius Traveler 6000Z mouse.